# How many complex numbers have $|z|<1$ such that $az ^ 4 + z ^ 3 + bz ^ 2 + cz + d = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let the four positive numbers $a, b, c, d$ satisfy $a + b + c + d <1$. Ask how many complex numbers have $|z|<1$ such that $$az ^ 4 + z ^ 3 + bz ^ 2 + cz + d = 0$$

Comment: Have you done anything on this?  What have you tried?  What went wrong?

Comment: This problem is difficult so I have not determined the solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

If $g(z)=z^3$, we can appeal to [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) since for $|z|=1$
$$|f(z)-g(z)| = |az^4+bz^2+cz+d|\le a+b+c+d <1 <|f(z)| + |g(z)|$$

Comment: The problem is how many complexes $z$ satisfy. From your hint I still have not found a solution. Please help me!

Comment: @Mary did you read the conclusion of Rouché’s theorem?